# Laravel - How can I query months and yearly dates?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and not really sure how to do this.

I record dates in my database as `start_day` in my `times` table.
Date is persisted with the following format: `2019-10-03`

Right now all I have is:

```
$months = DB::table('times')->where('start_day', '=', 2019)
```

How should I select data for each month of the year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `whereYear`

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$months = DB::table('times')->whereYear('start_day', (string) Carbon::now()->year)->get();
```

If you want to select months only then

```
$months = DB::table('times')->select(DB::raw('MONTH(start_day) month')->whereYear('start_day', (string) Carbon::now()->year)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `where()` to `whereYear()` to search by year.

```
$months = DB::table('times')->whereYear('start_day', '=', 2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

write

```
$month = array():
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
   $month[] = DB::table('times')->whereYear('start_day','2019')->whereMonth('start_day',$i)->get();
}
```

OR

```
$month = array():
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
   $month[] = DB::table('times')->where([['YEAR(start_day)', '=', 2019],['MONTH(start_day)','=',(int)$i]])->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try monthly , weekly , yearly in this format

```
$weeklyNumberOfSales = Sale::whereBetween('order_date', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
        ->sum('qty');

 $monthlyNumberOfSales = Sale::whereMonth('order_date',Carbon::now()->format('m'))
        ->sum('qty');

$yearlyNumberOfSales = Sale::whereYear('order_date',Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
        ->sum('qty');
```

model name **Sale** .
'**order_date**' and '**qty**' are the field name